# CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers() return Empty

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, rxtx

I have two Serial Com port ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1, ttyUSB0 is used by Test1.class and ttyUSB1 is used by Test2.class.
Both Test1.class and Test2.class access same LocalCommunication.class to check ports and connect and disconnect port.

LocalCommunication.class has below code to return various ports that are connected to RPI

```
CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()
```

And i get this empty for my Test1.class and for Test2.class return 2 port.

Can you help me what could be the issue.And how to debug this.

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution for this?, i have the same problem, thx

Comment: No, the got some error with RPI after reinstalling OS didn't get the issue. So ignored.